# How to show that a group homomorphism from $SL(2, \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)$ is one-to-one?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $n$ be an odd integer, and let $f:SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \to 
GL(n^2, \mathbb{C})$ be a group homomorphism. The special linear group
$SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ is known to have the following
presentations.

$$
\langle A, B  \mid 
A^n = 1, (AB)^3=B^2, B^4=1, (A^2 B A^{\frac{n+1}{2}} B)^3=1\rangle
$$

$$
\langle A, B  \mid 
A^n = B^2 = (AB)^3 = (A^{\frac{n+1}{2}}BA^4B)^2\rangle
$$

Suppose that the homomorphism $f$ has been defined by specifying 
$f(A)$ and $f(B)$. What are some
techniques to show that $f$ is one-to-one?

I hope someone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Check the kernel of $f$ and see if it is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the homomorphism is not injective, there needs to be a nontrivial kernel, which will be a normal subgroup, and thus contains a minimal normal subgroup. Now for each minimal normal subgroup of $SL_2(Z/nZ)$ a word in $A$ and $B$ that represents a nontrivial element in this subgroup. Evaluate these words in the generator images, then the homomorphism is one-to-one if and only if all these words evaluate nontrivial.

As for finding the minimal normal subgroups, if $n$ is prime, this is only the group generated by the scalar matrix for $-1$. If $n$ is a prime poer there also is the kernel of the congruence map modulo $n/p$. If $n$ has multiple prime factors, the group is a subdirect product of the images modulo the prime powers in $n$, then simply do the respective test for every prime power.

Exceptions: If n=2, there are three cyclic groups of order 2 (corresponding to the elements of order 2 in $(Z/2^kZ)^*$) and the congruence kernel splits in the direct sum of one of them and a subgroup of order $2^2$ (instead of $2^3$).

Comment: ahulpke, Thank you for your comments. Can you please give me a reference for the classification of minimal normal subgroups of $SL(2, \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$? For instance, when $n$ is the power of a prime $p$, why is the kernel of the congruence map modulo $n/p$ the only minimal normal subgroup?

Comment: @user683253 I'm not aware of a nice reference for this fact, but it follows because PSL is simple, and the modules below PSL are irreducible. That is, if a normal subgroup projects nontrivially to PSL, it then projects to all of PSKL, ditto for the layers between congruence kernels. Then the fact that there are no supplements to the congruence kernels shows that the normal subgroup must be a congruence kernel. (There are exceptions for small primes 2,3) References: in next comment

Comment: @user683253: The ideas of the proof are in: Weigel, Thomas
On a certain class of Frattini extensions of finite Chevalley groups. Groups of Lie type and their geometries (Como, 1993), 281–288, 
London Math. Soc. Lecture Note Ser., 207,   and  Detinko, A; Flannery, D. L.; Hulpke, A.
Zariski density and computing in arithmetic groups. (English summary) 
Math. Comp. 87 (2018), no. 310, 967–986.

Comment: @user683253 and (probably the easiest to read, as long as you understand German): Beisiegel, Bert
Die Automorphismengruppen homozyklischer p-Gruppen.
Arch. Math. (Basel) 29 (1977), no. 4, 363–366.